# Matlab dlmread adds random zeros

Tags: matlab

I need to add data to array in matlab, I trying to use dlmread, but it adds random zeroes, how could I define rows length?

My file:

```
1 65.058 5  0
2 80.661 46 0
3 102.083 197 1
4 80.529 111 5
5 88.331 160 6
```

My line:

```
X = dlmread(Data, ' ', 0, 0);
```

Output:

```
1.0000   65.0580    5.0000
     0         0         0
2.0000   80.6610   46.0000
     0         0         0
3.0000  102.0830  197.0000
1.0000         0         0
4.0000   80.5290  111.0000
5.0000         0         0
```

Comment: How are you generating your file?

Comment: This works for me. `X = dlmread('test.txt', ' '); X = X(:, 1:end-1);`

Comment: alternatively use `textscan` and specify %s %s %s for strings or %d %d %d for numbers. The reason for the 0 are because you have rows with 6 elements in length, so matlab has to pad the rows with less elements with 0 s or it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two consecutive spaces in the first line of your file. This causes `dlmread` to add an additional column. I can't recreate your output (my version is R2015b), but I'm suspecting this is the culprit. You don't need to (and can't) define the number of rows or columns with `dlmread`; it's supposed to figure it out for itself by design. This shouldn't be a problem when your input data matches the expected format.